# XElement creation if the value is not Null

Tags: c#, linq

I am trying to create XML from a List. I am creating a Anonymous class from the list to form XML:

```
var xEle = new XElement("Employees",
                from emp in empList
                select new XElement("Employee",
                             new XElement("ID", emp.ID),
                               new XElement("FName", emp.FName),
                             new XElement("LName", emp.LName)
                      ));
```

How do I handle if `Fname` or `Lname` is null?

Also I want to Add elements dynamically only if the object is not null. For example if `Fname` is null, I need to skip creating Fname:

```
new XElement("ID", emp.ID),
new XElement("LName", emp.LName)
```

How do I do that?

Comment: You haven't shown any anonymous classes.

Comment: `xEle` is just a query as it stands

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Your code doesn't actually show an anonymous type at all - just `XElement` creation. However, you can use the fact that LINQ to XML will ignore `null` values when adding content. So you can use:

```
select new XElement("Employee",
                    new XElement("ID", emp.ID),
                    emp.FName == null ? null : new XElement("FName", emp.FName),
                    emp.LName == null ? null : new XElement("LName", emp.LName)
                   )
```

Or you could write an extension method on `string`:

```
public static XElement ToXElement(this string content, XName name)
{
    return content == null ? null : new XElement(name, content);
}
```

And call it with:

```
select new XElement("Employee",
                    emp.ID.ToXElement("ID"),
                    emp.FName.ToXElement("FName"),
                    emp.LName.ToXElement("LName"))
```

Comment: Didn't get back to my original comment soon enough to add this:  For an example of how I'm using this, please see my SO question here:  [Add columns to dataset to be used as XML parent nodes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18220709/add-columns-to-dataset-to-be-used-as-xml-parent-nodes)